# $window.open still opening url inside phonegap app (angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I have the following HTML and angular.js code:

```
<span ng-if="club.club_brief != ''">
  <a href="#" ng-click="openLink('{{club.club_brief}}')">Website</a>
</span>
```

In my controller:

```
$scope.openLink = function(url) {
    $window.open(url, '_system');
}
```

EDIT: 
Having read some answers I also tried

```
$window.open(url, '_system');
```

but I'm getting the same problem in that it's still loading the site within the app without trying to open a browser.

I was hoping that would prevent the link from being open inside the phonegap app but it's not. I want it to open in a new browser (or give the option of the browser). This is for Android.

Comment: You want that link to open up in a new tab, versus in the current tab?

Comment: Ive updated the question for more clarity. Its a phonegap app for Android so I want it to fire up a prompt to open an actual mobile browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this will work directly.  you probably need to call the service for this through phonegap.

Comment: Thanks I think this might be the issue alright. I will find out more information and give this the correct answer

Comment: I think there is already a method for this if I remember it right.  Let me know , also curious.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$window.open(url, '_blank');`

Comment: I havent tried that actually, im not sure why i figured that wouldnt work, will check now

Comment: no same problem unfortunately, its not using the phones browser

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using _blank. It's possible your current tab is _system.

```
$scope.openLink = function(url) {
    $window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could not use `{{}}` interpolation inside `ng-click`, if you do it then you will get an `$parser` error in console.

**Markup**

```
<span ng-if="club.club_brief != ''">
  <a href="#" ng-click="openLink(club.club_brief)">Website</a>
</span>
```

Other think you should use `_blank` while opening tab from the JavaScript tag.

```
$window.open(url, "_blank")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but It doesnt even load the url without `{{}}` it just renders `club.club_brief`. I have also tried `_blank` but getting the same issue

Comment: @Adrian are you sure you have value in `club.club_brief`

Comment: yep to be honest that isnt the issue, the value is passing perfectly fine into the function, its loading the correct website, just not loading it from the phones browser , its using the app instead

Answer (score 0):

A workaround could be to use

```
<a href="{{club.club_brief}}" target="_blank">Website</a>
```

As a sidenote, when using `ng-click` you can just write

```
<a href="#" ng-click="openLink(club.club_brief)">Website</a>
```

No need for `{{ }}` or `''`.

Comment: I already answered that..he might have some check or conditional thing..that why he went for `ng-click`